# Can I use std::shared_ptr to wrap per I/O data in IOCP?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2, iocp

I'm working on a client application that uses IOCP.

My per I/O data class is derived from WSAOVERLAPPED:

```
class IoRequest : public WSAOVERLAPPED
{
...
};
```

And when performing asynchronous I/O operations, I use it like this:

```
{ // WSASend - this is done in my main thread.
    IoRequest *pIoRequest = new IoRequest;
    pIoRequest->SetSocket(m_socket);
    pIoRequest->SetBuffer(vecCommandData);
    pIoRequest->SetOperationType(OP_TYPE_SEND);
    WSASend(m_socket, pIoRequest->GetWsaBuffer(), 1, NULL, 0, pIoRequest, NULL);
}

{ // WSARecv - this is done in my I/O worker thread.
    GetQueuedCompletionStatus(m_hIocp, &dwNumberOfBytesTransferred, &ulCompletionKey, (LPOVERLAPPED*)&pIoRequest, INFINITE);
    ...
    WSARecv(pIoRequest->GetSocket(), pIoRequest->GetWsaBuffer(), 1, NULL, &(pIoRequest->GetFlags()), pIoRequest, NULL);
    ...
}
```

I reuse my IoRequest instance in my worker thread routine.  I wonder, will there be any problem using std::shared_ptr instead of a raw pointer to manage my per I/O data?

So for WSASend(), something like:

```
std::shared_ptr<IoRequest> spIoRequest(new IoRequest);
spIoRequest->SetSocket(m_socket);
spIoRequest->SetBuffer(vecCommandData);
spIoRequest->SetOperationType(OP_TYPE_SEND);
WSASend(m_socket, spIoRequest->GetWsaBuffer(), 1, NULL, 0, spIoRequest.get(), NULL);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a live instance of `std::shared_ptr<IoRequest>` somewhere, your `IoRequest` will be deallocated at the end of the sending routine before the completion handler receives it.

Comment: @Remy, thanks for the input, but I prefer editing my answers myself. That deallocation might happen right in the middle of the receiving callback for all we know.